# How to solve this kernel bug on OS start?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-panic

I just installed a new fresh Ubuntu 12.04.5 on a Dell laptop, I had 14.04 but as I really love 12.04 *stability* I decided to get back to it.

I have a Windows installed alongside which I just keep to have a way to preserve laptop warranty somehow.

So, I had used 14.04 with out any problem, but now I just installed on first boot I can see this right after the Ubuntu start screen appears:

[image]

So how could I solve this? Something strange I can notice is that I can't see any GRUB screen on start but it goes right to this purple Ubuntu start splash screen, and then that black screen with error log will appear.

This is the `lshw` output:

```
PCI (sysfs)  
ubuntu                    
    description: Portable Computer
    product: Inspiron 5548 (Inspiron 5548)
    vendor: Winbond Electronics
    version: A03
    serial: 9G6XX32
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 ldt16 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=portable sku=Inspiron 5548 uuid=44454C4C-4700-1036-8058-B9C04F583332
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 079JDM
       vendor: Winbond Electronics
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: .9G6XX32.CN1296654T012D.
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Winbond Electronics
          physical id: 0
          version: A03
          date: 01/23/2015
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 500MHz
          capacity: 3GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 4MiB
             capacity: 4MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1f
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: 8KTF51264HZ-1G6N1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 0
             serial: 14577691
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: 8KTF51264HZ-1G6N1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 1
             serial: 14577705
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:68 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:d2310000-d2313fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:62 memory:d2300000-d230ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:65 memory:d231b000-d231b01f
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: irq:67 memory:d2314000-d2317fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:58
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:59 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:d2200000-d22fffff ioport:d2000000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 07
                serial: 44:a8:42:e5:56:7c
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:64 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d2200000-d2200fff memory:d2000000-d2003fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:60 memory:d2100000-d21fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 3160
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 83
                serial: f4:06:69:8b:a8:df
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:66 memory:d2100000-d2101fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:61 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:d1000000-d1ffffff ioport:b0000000(size=268435456)
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: Display controller
                product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:d1000000-d103ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1040000-d105ffff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:d2319000-d23193ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:63 ioport:5088(size=8) ioport:5094(size=4) ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5090(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:d2318000-d23187ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:d231a000-d231a0ff ioport:5040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST1000LM014-1EJ1
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: DEMB
             serial: W382ZY1K
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=43f7b361-e7dd-4c94-b8a4-87a1fb57f286
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: FAT32
                serial: ce75-a3e7
                size: 495MiB
                capacity: 499MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI system partition
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: FAT32
                serial: 90e8-52e3
                size: 15MiB
                capacity: 39MiB
                capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=Basic data partition
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows reserved partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                serial: 2fcd06b3-9aee-4e34-918e-a4b012138316
                capacity: 127MiB
                capabilities: nofs
                configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                version: 3.1
                serial: aceb-6180
                size: 720MiB
                capacity: 749MiB
                capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-04-29 18:18:40 filesystem=ntfs label=WINRETOOLS modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:4
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 3.1
                serial: 162ec8d8-0675-6d46-a725-d70f394493d1
                size: 466GiB
                capacity: 466GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-04-29 18:18:49 filesystem=ntfs label=OS name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:5
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                version: 1.0
                serial: 74fa39ea-06d3-4539-a96c-9946e3a4b80f
                size: 146GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2015-08-17 05:02:33 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2015-08-17 05:18:18 mounted=2015-08-17 05:26:37 name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:6
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 7
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,7
                logical name: /dev/sda7
                version: 3.1
                serial: 94751caa-e0ab-8746-8cfe-a0d8bc72dc76
                size: 309GiB
                capacity: 309GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-07-24 10:54:38 filesystem=ntfs label=DATA modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:7
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 8
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,8
                logical name: /dev/sda8
                version: 3.1
                serial: 7457-ed72
                size: 7836MiB
                capacity: 7844MiB
                capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-04-29 20:09:04 filesystem=ntfs label=PBR Image modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Microsoft recovery partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          bus info: usb@2:1
          logical name: scsi3
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             size: 14GiB (15GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: signature=d1b1ac36
           *-volume
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: SYSLINUX
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /cdrom
                version: FAT32
                serial: d47c-f2ce
                size: 14GiB
                capacity: 14GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 3
          bus info: usb@2:7
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=rts5139
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: xD/SD/M.S.
             vendor: Generic-
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdc
             version: 1.00
             serial: 3
             capabilities: removable
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdc
  *-battery
       product: DELL VVMKC53K
       vendor: SDI
       physical id: 1
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 39000mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.4V
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM Define 1
       product: OEM Define 5
       vendor: OEM Define 2
       physical id: 2
       version: OEM Define 6
       serial: OEM Define 3
       capacity: 75mWh
```

Comment: And nothing happens after this black screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fully turn off your Intel Rapid Start and Secure Boot, and try it from BIOS, if you have a pre-installed 64-bit Windows 8 with UEFI, since it is pre-installed, and you also need 64-bit ubuntu, try this

https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported